# Linux system call to discover the filesystem of a device

Tags: linux, filesystems, system

My question is the following: I need to get the filesystem of a device (a pendrive in my case) to use this information. My application is running in a Linux embedded system and I want to accept only pendrives with FAT and FAT32 filesystem to perform a file exportation. I searched the internet, but I didn't find what is the system call that I need.
About the source code, my application is being written in C++.

I already used the struct statfs, however after a test I discover that the value of the field f_type is the same when I use a NTFS and a FAT32 formatted pendrive. The output of the test is the value 0x1021994.

I know that is possible to discover the filesystem, the "fdisk -l" command do the job, however I can't figure out in the fdisk code how.

Comment: I am not sure at all that you are right to reject a non VFAT filesystem on an USB stick. I find quite useful to format my USB stick with an Ext3 (or Ext4) file system.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `statfs` [system call](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/statfs.2.html) which includes `uint32_t f_type; /* type of filesystem */` in the returned `struct statfs`

---

**Note** that, as [JoshuaRLi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5348393/joshuarli) points out, `statfs` is now deprecated in favor of `statvfs` — and `struct statvfs` does ***not*** include an `f_type` field.

Comment: Note that `statfs` is [deprecated](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html#NOTES) in favor of `statvfs`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

1) Run the ["mount"](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) command to list one or more filesystems

2) Parse out the information you need

3) You can invoke "mount" from the ["popen()"](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) API

PS:

There's also a ["mount()"](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount) API, which could eliminate steps 2) and 3), if you prefer.

Linux being Linux, there's also probably at least half a dozen other viable alternatives - your choice :)

Comment: The mount command only list the devices that are mounted. In my case I need to check the filesystem before mounting the device.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could parse `/proc/mounts` file?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the filesystem type when mounting (do not use the default `-t auto`). If you need to support multiple types, consider trying them all.